# tooltip on mouseover image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on 2 functions; I created an image map for an image and want if someone hovers over this part of the image that on the right the price appears and a tooltip under the mouse that says "Discover" or similar.

Right now I have the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function writeText(txt) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src ="test.png" alt="Jacket" usemap="#jacket" />

<p id="test"></p>
<map name="jacket">
    <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213"href="test"; title="Discover" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area href="test"; title="Shop Now" alt="Discover" shape="poly" coords="221,215,183,218,190,164" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" />
</map> 
</map> 

</body>
</html>
```

However there are a few problems:

1. The price does not disappear if the customer does not hover over the area
2. I am unable to show a tooltip.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix these problems?
I appreciate your help
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following attribute to remove the price:

```
onmouseout="writeText('')"
```

And, you have extra semi-colons that may be the problem with your title not appearing. Try this instead:

```
<map name="jacket">
   <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213" href="test" title="Discover" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" onmouseout="writeText('')" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
   <area href="https://jerry123.myshopify.com/products/product1" title="Shop Now" alt="Discover" shape="poly" coords="221,215,183,218,190,164" onmouseover="writeText('$60')" onmouseout="writeText('')" />
```

Comment: the title appears however I want this to be in a little box that appears under the mouse.

Comment: How does the title appear? Are you talking about the browser tooltip? If you want some other tip to appear and track the mouse then you are going to have to do something far more advanced.

Comment: That is definitely an example of "more advanced". You should use jQuery (or equiv) and track the mouse movement, and move/show/hide the tip. Net-a-porter uses jQuery to do this. Please accept my answer if it has helped.

Comment: Thanks Keith I ended up using qTip2 for mousetracking